# How do I control fan speed on my Lenovo laptop?

Tags: lenovo, fan

My Lenovo laptop (Yoga 730-131KB) has a very loud fan when booting into Ubuntu 18.04. I've looked into the fancontrol package, but whenever I try and configure it I run into the error

`/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`

Are there any other programs I can use, or maybe some advice on how to get around the error?

Comment: Do you have HWE enabled?  A quick scan showed there is a good chance you're using older software than your device if you aren't using the later kernel/hardware stack enabled by HWE.

Comment: you need to run sensors-config first to see what it can detect.  Pay attention to the Super IO section.